# load data infile parameterized

Tags: linux, shell, mariadb

i need to load data from flat file into mariaDB on linux environment.
i've plan to put mariaDB script on shell file. then call shell from cron.

mariadb script shown as follow:

```
set @path = (select path_file from param);

set @tbl = (select table_name from param);

set @x = concat(
            'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ',
             @path,
            ' INTO TABLE ', @tbl,
           ' (@row) set id = trim(substr(@row,1,2)), name = trim(substr(@row,3,19)), address= trim(substr(@row,22,20))'
            );

prepare y from @x;

execute y;

deallocate prepare y;
```

when i execute the script directly on heidisql, 
error shown:

```
this command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet
```

does any one have better way to load data from flat file into MariaDB on linux environment regularly (scheduled) without using any ETL tools?

Thanks.

Comment: I woluld suggest to try preparing the SQL in bash, and then run the sql like:
mysql -u username -p database < temp.sql

Comment: could you give me some example, please?

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is (adjust as needed):

File: `load_data.sh`

```bash
path=$(mysql -u ${mysql_user} -p${mysql_password} -s -N <<GET_PATH
  SELECT '/path/to/file/data.csv';
GET_PATH
)

tbl=$(mysql -u ${mysql_user} -p${mysql_password} -s -N <<GET_TABLE
  SELECT 'table';
GET_TABLE
)

# mysql -u ${mysql_user} -p${mysql_password} -s -N <<LOAD_DATA
#   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${path}'
#   INTO TABLE \`${tbl}\` ...
# LOAD_DATA

# TEST
cat <<LOAD_DATA
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${path}'
  INTO TABLE \`${tbl}\` ...
LOAD_DATA
```

Command line:

```bash
$ ls -l
-r-x------ load_data.sh

$ ./load_data.sh 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/data.csv'
INTO TABLE `table` ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, write as much of the SQL into a `STORED PROCEDURE`.  *Then* use bash to call that SP.